# Select multiple image files using fileupload control(ASP.net C#) and save it in database in one click.

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am able to select multiple files using fileupload control but when I try to save it to a database it's giving me an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFiles)
{
     foreach (HttpPostedFile uploaded in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
     {
         bindata = new BinaryReader(uploaded.InputStream);
         ImageByteArray = bindata.ReadBytes(uploaded.ContentLength);

         // byte array is sent to a method
         dbmt.SaveImageToDB(ImageByteArray);
     }
}
```

And the following is my code for the SaveImageToDB method

```
public void SaveImageToDB(byte[] ImageByteArray)
{
    try
    {
        scon.Open();
        scm.Connection = scon;

        scm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        scm.CommandText = "SaveProfileImage";

        SqlParameter paramImgArray = scm.Parameters.Add("@ImgBody", SqlDbType.Image,0);
        paramImgArray.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        paramImgArray.Value = ImageByteArray;

        scm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch( SqlException sqx )
    {
        throw sqx;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line of your code are you getting this error?

Comment: It's occurring in the dbmt.SaveImageToDB(). After creating ImageByteArray( Byte[] ), I'll send it to the method dbmt.SaveImageToDB(ImageByteArray). I would even test it before calling the method by using "if(ImageByteArray != null )" and it's not null.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is go through each file selected and convert each to a byte array, and send to the method so it can be save it in the database.

Comment: Have you used the asp.net debugger to step through the code ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t6y55xx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? Doing this and inspecting the elements or seting watches as you go will point you as to what object is null.

Comment: Thanks. Just got back from a vacation. Thanks for that question. It prompted me to look at the right place. The problem was that I did not initialize my object that was calling a function within the appcode. What I did was DBmiddleTier dbmt; instead of DBmiddleTier dbmt = new DBmiddleTier();. That is why the program though that the dbmt was null. It started working as soon as I changed it. Thank you very much for your help guys. I should have started using this site a long time ago when I was still at school.

Answer (score 0):

Set The Property **AllowMultiple = True** in fileupload control.

```
protected void uploadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (UploadImages.HasFiles)
   {
       foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in UploadImages.PostedFiles)
       {
           uploadedFile.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"),
           uploadedFile.FileName));
           listofuploadedfiles.Text += String.Format("{0}<br/>", uploadedFile.FileName);
       }
   }
```

}

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't so clear. It's my first time here. I have set the AllowMultiple to true. I am able to select multiple files using fileupload.  What I'm trying to do is go through each file selected and convert each to a byte array, and send to the method so it can be save in the database.

Comment: Thanks. Just got back from a vacation. Thanks for that question. It prompted me to look at the right place. The problem was that I did not initialize my object that was calling a function within the appcode. What I did was DBmiddleTier dbmt; instead of DBmiddleTier dbmt = new DBmiddleTier();. That is why the program though that the dbmt was null. It started working as soon as I changed it. Thank you very much for your help guys. I should have started using this site a long time ago when I was still at school.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is giving an error in the said method, but on which line inside that method is giving this error?

I assume that the method you have given here is complete (i.e. there is no code which you have deleted before pasting it here), so i guess there are only 2 objects which could be null and those are "scon" and "scm". Put a breakpoint on the line "scon.Open();" and on line "scm.Connection = scon;". Once the execution stops on each of these lines, hover your mouse over "scon" and then over "scm". I guess either one of them will be null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just got back from a vacation. Thanks for that question. It prompted me to look at the right place. The problem was that I did not initialize my object that was calling a function within the appcode. What I did was DBmiddleTier dbmt; instead of DBmiddleTier dbmt = new DBmiddleTier();. That is why the program though that the dbmt was null. It started working as soon as I changed it. Thank you very much for your help guys. I should have started using this site a long time ago when I was still at school.

Comment: If this answer was helpful then please upvote and/or mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my object. It was not instantiated correctly. I was accessing a class within appcode called DBmiddleTier to access a database and write the image file. Here is what I did wrong: DBMiddleTier dbmt; <-----"WRONG". Here is what I did to correct the problem  DBMiddleTier dbmt = new DBMiddleTier();